# Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I was trying to use struts2 framework while making web projects when I met the problem of title.I'm new to stackoverflow, so if the code is hard to read, please forgive me.
Here's my struct.xml

```
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action  name="login" class="com.mxl.actions.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.i18n.encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="gb2312"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<s:form action="login" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="username" label="User Name"
        cssStyle="width:160px;height:26px;" />
    <s:password name="password" label="Pass Word"
        cssStyle="width:160px;height:26px;" />
    <s:submit value="Sign in" />
</s:form>
```

And finally LoginAction.java

```
package com.mxl.actions;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        if(username.equals("1") && password.equals("111")){
            return SUCCESS;
        }else{
            return INPUT;
        }
    }
    public String getName() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

When I click "Run on Server" the project looks fine,and when I type in the user name and password it goes "404 Not Found" the URL turns to `localhost:8080/Struts_try/login` I hope someone could help me out.

Comment: I have put the required jar file into the `WEB-INF/lib` and have fixed the Build Path.

Comment: Just a curiosity Here's my struct.xml it's a error of typing? should  Here's my strust.xml

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a member variable `name` inside you action class.

When invoking the action, the default configuration  maps the http parameters calling the setter. As an example if you call `localhost:8080/Struts_try/login?name=myName` Struts2 will instance your action and call the method `setName("myName")` (if your property is not a string, struts2 will try to convert it).

After the action execution, when the results are displayed in the view (say,a JSP page), you might write `<s:property value='name' />` and Struts2 will invoke the method `getName()` of your action.

**So it is important to set and get values using getters and setters instead of using member variable directly.**

Comment: I've added getters and setters in my .java file and it still doesn't work.